Exercise regarding complete $q$-trees
I am trying to prove the following Lemma/Exercise:

Let $W$ be a complete q-Tree with $n$ leaves. Then $(q-1)|(n-1)$.

Approach:
In level $0$, we have $1$ Knot, the root.
In Level $1$, we have $q$ knots, since we assume $W$ to be a complete $q$-tree.
Let $m$ the level of the leaves, in level $m$ we have $q^m$ leaves.
So the statement of the Lemma is, $(q-1)|(q^m-1)$.
By Polynomial division we get $\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}= q^{m-1}+q^{m-2}+...+q+1$. I.e. $(q-1)(q^{m-1}+q^{m-2}+...+q+1)=q^m-1$, thus the statement holds.
But, the hint in the exercise did state "this can easily be shown by induction". This lead to the questions: Is my prove correct? And how does one show it by induction?

Can you define what a complete q-Tree is?

@CalvinLin A Tree where every knot has exactly $q$ successors.

Your proof is NOT incorrect but you can also prove the same thing by inducting on the number of levels.
Let $T$ be a complete q-tree and let $n$ be the number of leaves in $T$. If $T$ has only one level, clearly $q-1$ divides $1-1 = 0$. If $T$ has $k>1$ levels, obtain $T'$ by removing the last level. Let $n'$ be the number of leaves in $T'$. Observe that $T'$ is a complete q-tree with $<k$ (in particular $k-1$) levels and that $\displaystyle n'=\frac{n}{q}$. By induction hypothesis, $(q-1)\big|(n'-1)$ i.e., $\displaystyle (q-1)\bigg|\left(\frac{n}{q} -1\right)$ and from here it is easy to prove $(q-1)\big|(n-1)$.
A couple of comments: There is already a fairly standard term for trees in which each node has at most $q$ childern, $q$-ary tree. And what you call a complete $q$-tree is exactly the same as a complete $q$-ary tree. And the letter $n$ is commonly reserved for the order (the number of vertices) of the graph. It is good practice to stick to stick to standard convention if there is any. If you found this question as is in some text book, I am not sure how to react. I'd call the authors wild.

How would you show the last step which is easy to prove?

@MathieuRundström Since $\displaystyle (q-1)\bigg|\left(\frac{n}{q} -1\right)$, there is a natural number $k$ such that $\displaystyle k \cdot (q-1)=\left(\frac{n}{q} -1\right)$. Now try writing $n-1$ in terms of $q$ and $k$.
